# Utilizar função de validação em diferentes campos HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho a seguinte função em javascript para validação do NIF:

```
    //VALIDAÇÃO NIF
    validaContribuinte = function(){
        var contribuinte = $('#nif').val();
        var temErro=0;
        if (
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '1' && // pessoa singular
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '2' && // pessoa singular
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '3' && // pessoa singular
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '45' && // pessoa singular não residente
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '5' && // pessoa colectiva
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '6' && // administração pública
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '70' && // herança indivisa
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '71' && // pessoa colectiva não residente
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '72' && // fundos de investimento
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '77' && // atribuição oficiosa
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '79' && // regime excepcional
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '8' && // empresário em nome individual (extinto)
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '90' && // condominios e sociedades irregulares
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '91' && // condominios e sociedades irregulares
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '98' && // não residentes
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '99' // sociedades civis

        ) { temErro=1;}
        var check1 = contribuinte.substr(0,1)*9;
        var check2 = contribuinte.substr(1,1)*8;
        var check3 = contribuinte.substr(2,1)*7;
        var check4 = contribuinte.substr(3,1)*6;
        var check5 = contribuinte.substr(4,1)*5;
        var check6 = contribuinte.substr(5,1)*4;
        var check7 = contribuinte.substr(6,1)*3;
        var check8 = contribuinte.substr(7,1)*2;

        var total= check1 + check2 + check3 + check4 + check5 + check6 + check7 + check8;
        var divisao= total / 11;
        var modulo11=total - parseInt(divisao)*11;
        if ( modulo11==1 || modulo11==0){ comparador=0; } // excepção
        else { comparador= 11-modulo11;}


        var ultimoDigito=contribuinte.substr(8,1)*1;
        if ( ultimoDigito != comparador ){ temErro=1;}

        if (temErro==1){
            alert('NIF Inválido' );
            $('#nif').val("");
        }
    }
```

Como posso adaptar esta função para fazer esta validação em campos de HTML diferentes? Neste caso estou a passar o id do campo nif: `var contribuinte = $('#nif').val();`. Se eu quiser fazer a validação para dois inputs diferentes como posso fazê-lo?

Comment: como tu chama `validaContribuinte()`? quando?

Comment: no input de cada campo através do método onBlur

Comment: @HugoMachado eu sei que é meio OFF, mas voce poderia me passar o site onde você obteve essa regra de validação do NIF? Valeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa generalizar sua função para poder chamar para cada campo.
Em vez de procurar pelo "`$('#nif')`", procure por um campo genérico - que pode ser "nif1" ou "nif2", ou qualquer que seja o ID dele, especificado por um parâmetro da função de validação:

```js
$('#nif1').change(function(){
  validaContribuinte('nif1');
});
$('#nif2').change(function(){
  validaContribuinte('nif2');
});

//VALIDAÇÃO NIF
    validaContribuinte = function(inputID){
        var contribuinte = $('#'+inputID).val();
        var temErro=0;
        if (
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '1' && // pessoa singular
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '2' && // pessoa singular
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '3' && // pessoa singular
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '45' && // pessoa singular não residente
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '5' && // pessoa colectiva
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '6' && // administração pública
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '70' && // herança indivisa
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '71' && // pessoa colectiva não residente
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '72' && // fundos de investimento
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '77' && // atribuição oficiosa
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '79' && // regime excepcional
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '8' && // empresário em nome individual (extinto)
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '90' && // condominios e sociedades irregulares
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '91' && // condominios e sociedades irregulares
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '98' && // não residentes
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '99' // sociedades civis

        ) { temErro=1;}
        var check1 = contribuinte.substr(0,1)*9;
        var check2 = contribuinte.substr(1,1)*8;
        var check3 = contribuinte.substr(2,1)*7;
        var check4 = contribuinte.substr(3,1)*6;
        var check5 = contribuinte.substr(4,1)*5;
        var check6 = contribuinte.substr(5,1)*4;
        var check7 = contribuinte.substr(6,1)*3;
        var check8 = contribuinte.substr(7,1)*2;

        var total= check1 + check2 + check3 + check4 + check5 + check6 + check7 + check8;
        var divisao= total / 11;
        var modulo11=total - parseInt(divisao)*11;
        if ( modulo11==1 || modulo11==0){ comparador=0; } // excepção
        else { comparador= 11-modulo11;}


        var ultimoDigito=contribuinte.substr(8,1)*1;
        if ( ultimoDigito != comparador ){ temErro=1;}

        if (temErro==1){
            alert('NIF Inválido' );
            $('#'+inputID).val("");
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <label for="nif1">NIF #1:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nif1" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="nif2">NIF #2:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nif2" />
</p>
```

Comment: Não testei o seu código, de qualquer das formas obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar uma classe para aplicar a validação. Nesse caso usei a classe `nif` nos inputs.

```js
$('.nif').blur(function(){
        var contribuinte = $.trim($(this).val());
    
        var temErro=0;
        if (
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '1' && // pessoa singular
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '2' && // pessoa singular
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '3' && // pessoa singular
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '45' && // pessoa singular não residente
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '5' && // pessoa colectiva
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '6' && // administração pública
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '70' && // herança indivisa
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '71' && // pessoa colectiva não residente
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '72' && // fundos de investimento
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '77' && // atribuição oficiosa
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '79' && // regime excepcional
            contribuinte.substr(0,1) != '8' && // empresário em nome individual (extinto)
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '90' && // condominios e sociedades irregulares
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '91' && // condominios e sociedades irregulares
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '98' && // não residentes
            contribuinte.substr(0,2) != '99' // sociedades civis

        ) { temErro=1;}
        var check1 = contribuinte.substr(0,1)*9;
        var check2 = contribuinte.substr(1,1)*8;
        var check3 = contribuinte.substr(2,1)*7;
        var check4 = contribuinte.substr(3,1)*6;
        var check5 = contribuinte.substr(4,1)*5;
        var check6 = contribuinte.substr(5,1)*4;
        var check7 = contribuinte.substr(6,1)*3;
        var check8 = contribuinte.substr(7,1)*2;

        var total= check1 + check2 + check3 + check4 + check5 + check6 + check7 + check8;
        var divisao= total / 11;
        var modulo11=total - parseInt(divisao)*11;
        if ( modulo11==1 || modulo11==0){ comparador=0; } // excepção
        else { comparador= 11-modulo11;}


        var ultimoDigito=contribuinte.substr(8,1)*1;
        if ( ultimoDigito != comparador ){ temErro=1;}

        if (temErro==1){
            alert('NIF Inválido' );
            $(this).focus().val("");
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="nif1" class="nif" /><br />
<input name="nif2" class="nif" /><br />
<input name="nif3" class="nif" /><br />
<input name="nif4" class="nif" /><br />
```

Adicionei um `focus()` no final pra voltar pro elemento com erro.

Comment: Funcional :) Obrigado pela ajuda !!